# Filtering records in Pandas python - syntax error

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this:

```
       duration  distance  speed  hincome  fi_cost     type
0           359      1601      4        3    40.00  cycling
1           625      3440      6        3    86.00  cycling
2           827      4096      5        3   102.00  cycling
3          1144      5704      5        2   143.00  cycling
```

If I use the following I export a new csv that pulls only those records with a distance less than 5000.

```
distance_1 = all_results[all_results.distance < 5000]
distance_1.to_csv('./distance_1.csv',",")
```

Now, I wish to export a csv with values from 5001 to 10000. I can't seem to get the syntax right...

```
distance_2 = all_results[10000 > all_results.distance < 5001]
distance_2.to_csv('./distance_2.csv',",")
```

Comment: you have the conditions reversed? (in the opp order :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately because of how Python chained comparisons work, we can't use the 50 < x < 100 syntax when `x` is some vectorlike quantity.  You have several options.

You could create two boolean Series and use `&` to combine them:

```
>>> all_results[(all_results.distance > 3000) & (all_results.distance < 5000)]
   duration  distance  speed  hincome  fi_cost     type
1       625      3440      6        3       86  cycling
2       827      4096      5        3      102  cycling
```

Use `between` to create a boolean Series and then use that to index (note that it's inclusive by default, though):

```
>>> all_results[all_results.distance.between(3000, 5000)] # inclusive by default
   duration  distance  speed  hincome  fi_cost     type
1       625      3440      6        3       86  cycling
2       827      4096      5        3      102  cycling
```

Or finally you could use `.query`:

```
>>> all_results.query("3000 < distance < 5000")
   duration  distance  speed  hincome  fi_cost     type
1       625      3440      6        3       86  cycling
2       827      4096      5        3      102  cycling
```

Answer (score 0):

```
5001 < all_results.distance < 10000
```

Comment: distance_2 = all_results[5001 < all_results.distance < 10000]
distance_2.to_csv('./distance_2.csv',",")

results in: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: that is the famous error ..., and @DSM just provided the answer.

Comment: Thanks ;) Makes sense!